# File upload via multipart-form-data using WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, file-upload, webclient, multipartform-data

can someone tell me how to upload a file in multipart-form-data , so that I can add post-params and file as a content .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need both `files` and objects in the payload you can use a `multipart` form like this:

**Form**

```
<form id="createForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:5000/api/send">
<input type="text" name="Field1"  id="field1" />
<input type="text" name="Field2"  id="field2" />
<input type="file" id="bulk" name="Bulk" required />
</form>
```

**POCO**

```
class MyClass
{
  public string Field1{get;set;}
  public string Field2{get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**
In the controller you can access the files using `Request.Form.Files` which gives you a collection with all your uploaded files.Then you can read your file(s) using a `StreamReader` like i do below:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/send")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit] 
public async Task<long> CreateAsync(MyClass obj) {
{
  var file=this.Request.Form.Files[0];  //there's only one in our form
  using(StreamReader reader=new StreamReader(file))
  {
    var data=await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("File Content:"+data);
    Console.WriteLine("{ Field1 :"+obj.Field1.ToString()+",Field2:"+obj.Field2.ToString()+"}");
  }

}
```

**Caution**
Take care when dealing with `multipart` since you will also need to specify the `maximum` size of a segment.
That is done in the `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => {
                    options.ValueCountLimit = 200;
                    options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
                });
 }
```

or like i did it  directly in the `Controller`-s method , by decorating it with `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` attribute.